# How can I listen on multiple sockets in Perl?

Tags: perl, sockets

I want to listen on different sockets on a TCP/IP client written in Perl. I know I 
have to use [select()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/select.html) but I don't know exactly how to implement it.

Can someone show me examples?

Comment: You might want to check out Network Programming with Perl. It's a bit dated, but the topic hasn't changed that much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the IO::Select module.    `perldoc IO::Select`   includes an example.

Here's a client example.  Not guarneteed to be typo free or even work right:

```
use IO::Select;
use IO::Socket;
# also look at IO::Handle, which IO::Select inherits from

$lsn1 = IO::Socket::INET->new(PeerAddr=>'example.org', PeerPort=>8000, Proto=>'tcp');
$lsn2 = IO::Socket::INET->new(PeerAddr=>'example.org', PeerPort=>8001, Proto=>'tcp');
$lsn3 = IO::Socket::INET->new(PeerAddr=>'example.org', PeerPort=>8002, Proto=>'tcp');
$sel = IO::Select->new;
$sel->add($lsn1);
$sel->add($lsn2);
# don't add the third socket to the select if you are never going to read form it.

while(@ready = $sel->can_read) {
    foreach $fh (@ready) {
        #read your data
        my $line = $fh->getline();
        # do something with $line
        #print the results on a third socket
        $lsn3->print("blahblahblah");
    }
}
```

---

this was too big to put in a comment field

You need to better define what you want to do.  You have stated that you need to read from port A and write to port B.  This is what the above code does.  It waits for data to come in on the sockets $lsn1 and $lsn2 (ports 8000 and 8001), reads a line, then writes something back out to example.com on port 8002 (socket $lsn3).

Note that select is really only necessary if you need to read from multiple sockets.  If you strictly need to read from only one socket, then scrap the IO::Select object and the while loop and just do `$line = < $lsn1 >` .  That will block until a line is received.

Anyway, by your definition, the above code is a client.  The code does actively connect to the server (example.org in this case).  I suggest you read up on how IO::Socket::INET works.  The parameters control whether it's a listening socket or not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've looked at the example.
This code is for server. But I am implementing a client. I want the client to listen on port A and write to port B, or maybe write to prot A also. The example listen for multiple connection to the same port. I think it is different than what I want.

Comment: MadCoder, thank you again for the help. But the above code is still a server. A client usually actively try to connect to the server. The code you provide above is listening on the incoming message.

Comment: Alex, see main answer for my response

Comment: My bad. I was using socket() function call to create a socket directly. I will read up the documents. Thanks

Comment: Whenever something listens for incoming connections, it **is** a server. And if you don't want your script to listen on multiple ports, why are you asking for something that listens on multiple ports?